# Jmeter record and play scripts for performance testing

Tags: jmeter

I want to do a performance test of a website so i am creating a script that mimics user behaviour. I am using blazemeter to record those scripts and upload it in jmeter. I have two questions:
1) Do the results of a record and play script vary when run on another machine or a different time ?
2) I am getting a 400 bad request error in one of the steps of the recorded script.

What should i do ?
Is there any other way to test the web pages other than record and play ?

Answer (score 0):

The chance of getting a good load test from recording is minimal as modern web applications widely use dynamic [HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) HTTP Request Parameters for different reasons (security, tracking client state, etc)

So after recording your test scenario "skeleton" most likely you will need to perform so called **correlation**  - the process of

- detecting dynamic parameters
- extracting them using [JMeter Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and storing into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- and reusing the variables where required

Detecting parameters is quite simple: just record your test 2 times and compare request defaults: if you see differences - you will need to perform the correlation.

Extracting dynamic parameters is a bigger story, choosing the right extractor depends on response type, for example:

- for HTML response types use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- for XML/XHTML and in some cases HTML use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- for JSON - [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- for anything else - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) which works with any text (including all above response types)

Also be aware that there is a solution allowing to perform JMeter correlation in an automated manner so you won't to detect and handle the dynamic parameter manually, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and get back to you.